# how to search for newline in text file using emacs

Tags: search, emacs, newline

I am looking for a particular pattern using the ctrl+s search feature in emacs.

I am looking for 0,0,0 "newline"

Basically, there are lots of rows, some have 0,0,0 inside the middle of the row, but I want to specifically search for lines ending in 0,0,0 so I would like to add a newline at the end of the search string.

How do I do this in emacs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can input special characters by appending a C-q (`isearch-quote-char`, in isearch mode, that sort of mimics `quoted-insert`, default binding for that key combo in other modes).

So, in your case, you should use: `C-s 0,0,0 C-q C-j`, since C-q C-j inserts a newline.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to accomplish that is to use regexp isearch.  Use <kbd>C-M-s</kbd> instead of <kbd>C-s</kbd>, and search for `0,0,0$`.  (`$` is the regexp sign for matching the end of a line.)

Answer (score 2):

@juanleon and @legoscia have provided different answers, which solve different problems. You need to decide which is the problem you have.

The difference is this: do you want the found text to *include the newline character* (which is the same as `C-j`) itself, or not?

If you are going to replace the matching text found, for example, do you want to replace the newline character too, or do you want to replace only the matching text at the end of the line, i.e., the text just before the newline char? If the latter then end your match pattern with `$`. If the former then end your match pattern with `C-j` (a newline char).